# Insert current date time

Tags: mysql, time

I'm trying to insert the current date and time into a particular column and I am doing something wrong that I can't figure out.

I've tried: `UPDATE v_extradatacomputers SET LastRun=NOW();`

I've also tried `INSERT INTO v_extradatacomputers ( LastRun) VALUE ('NOW());`

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to mySQL so any guidance anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use '' between now() in the first try.

Also check that now() value is set with time() if the cell is set as integer or date("Y-m-d H:i:s") if it is as datetime, date("Y-m-d") for date cells and for any other format check that you have used varchar.

EDIT: by the way,  can you use mysql_error() to know what the exact SQL error is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Use " between now()" Where exactly would I put that. I've also made sure the cell is set to datetime. I've also tried timestamp but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Try writing simple quotes '' between the now function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to insert the current time and date you need to use `INSERT` not `UPDATE`. The syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (dateTimeColumn) VALUES (NOW())
```

Comment: @MichaelHayward **What** isn't working? Are you getting an error?